# MySQL / PHP - How to match an author id to a user id and display username

Tags: php, mysql

another question. I need to display a username and so what I'm doing is getting the author id (which is '1'), and then using a query saying get the username from the users table where the author id is the same as the user id.

My problem is that I'm getting the value of '1' returned as I've said above and the following is my code. Am I missing something here or...?

```
 $users = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$authorid'") or die($users . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));

 while($userData = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
    $postAuthor = $usersData['username'];
}
```

**Edit 1**

I said also mention the above information should show the name 'Dan'.

The user 'Dan' has a user id of 1 should the author id should be 1 (which it is) from the post row. This is the only use of anything to do with the user table so it's not being overridden anywhere. I'm so confused.

Comment: Learn about [`JOIN`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php) clause of SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should have been an error:

```
while($userData = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
       ^^ no s
    $postAuthor = $usersData['username'];
                    ^^ used different variable name
}
```

Note: Use prepared statements also in this case, you're using mysqli anyways.

```
$select = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
$select->bind_param('i', $author_id);
$select->execute();
$results = $select->get_result();

while($userData = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $postAuthor = $userData['username'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I just realised that I was using $authorid which doesn't exist. It had no value inside before I used it in the query so changing it to the actual variable made it work. Your answer helped though. I'll accept it when I can, I need to wait about 7 minutes. :)

Comment: @Dan just like the comment above, how are your tables connected? its just odd to see `$author_id` being used to select to a WHERE clause as `userid`, the way i see it you need to join users with the authors matching user ids according to (where) author id = 1

Comment: I have a users table and another table called posts. So in the posts table I have a post id (which is just used to tell the difference between posts) and an author id which might be the same for multiple ones (of course) and that (author id) needs to be matched against a user id (in the users table which is unique). The problem was I just stuck $authorid in the query and it wasn't used anywhere else.